# How to stop R shinyalert changing the size of plots/plot text

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

*Update* It seems that the issue is not strictly to do with using a modal but something to do with showtext. If you restart the session and remove showtext from the app, then the issue with the words will disappear - just a shame because then I cannot use my desired font in the browser. Here is some code in which showtext can be included or not. When showtext is used, the font size keeps changing when you switch the screen size or update etc., leading to the issues:

```
    library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(bslib)
# library(showtext)

# bs_global_theme()
# 
# font_add_google(name = "Jost")
# showtext_opts(dpi = 96)
# showtext_auto()

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".multicol {-webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */-moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */column-count: 2;}"))

  ),

  theme = bs_theme(version = 4,
                   fg = "#081825",
                   bg = "#ffffff",
                   base_font = font_google("Jost"),
                   primary = "#ededed"
  ),
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             fluidRow(column(10,
                             offset = 1,
                             plotOutput("distPlot")
             ))
      ),
      column(6,
             fluidRow(
               column(10,
                      offset = 1,
                      align = "center",
                      sliderInput("bins",
                                  "Number of bins:",
                                  min = 1,
                                  max = 50,
                                  value = 30))
             ),

      )
    ),

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  theme_set(theme_minimal(base_size = 20))

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- tibble(x = faithful[, 2])

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        ggplot(x) +
          geom_histogram(aes(x = x), bins = input$bins) +
          labs(title = "My title and other text gets jumbled up",
               subtitle = glue::glue("{input$bins} bins"))
    })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have an R shiny app that requires users to enter values within some specified range, and I want them to be able to type in the number so that it can be of any level of precision.

Simply using a slider is not the answer, because that won't allow the level of precision I would like. In addition, setting limits on the values that can be input with min and max is also not a solution, because it changes how the numbers are displayed in the text box and does not 'change' people's input numbers.

I have used shinyalert to show a modal when the user enters a value that is not permitted, and it reminds them of the permitted values. Unfortunately, when the modal loads in, it then weirdly changes the size of text in any plots that are displayed on the page. I think this might be because the modal opens in the same window, and it is of a different size to the window so the text resizes itself for some reason, and becomes all jumbled. https://daattali.com/shiny/shinyalert-demo/ You can kind of see in the demo for popups at the link there that the words on the page slightly shift, which may be a similar thing happening.

Is there any way to stop the modal from making the plots update in this way?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you add sample code for reproducibility?

Comment: I've added some code and realised it has something to do with the way showtext renders things, but can't work out how to fix it besides just getting rid of showtext (and therefore not using my chosen font)